# What kind of foam should I use as a replacement inside my headphones?

Tags: headphones, repair

I'm repairing my original Steel Series Black Siberia V1 headset which has a dead speaker driver on the right side. When I removed the earpiece I found that the foam inside that lies between the speaker and the outside grill to be disintegrating.

What kind of foam would be an appropriate replacement for this use case? Because it's housed inside the speaker I don't know if it was used cosmetically to hide the view of the driver or if there is some other reason important for audio reproduction.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to google for a supplier of "Acoustically Transparent Foam" wherever you are.

Here's an example from the UK https://willys-hifi.com/products/speaker-grille-foam

You're probably going to need to cut it to size but you'll need to buy the correct thickness.